# Calculations based on a dynamic cell

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am recording stats from games.  One sheet lists PLAYERS with their stats.  It includes a RATINGS formula based on performance standard of previous games.

One a second sheet, I list the results of the games.  One cell takes the current rating from PLAYERS/RATING, Then incorporates the current game stats and displays an updated NEW RATING.

This new ratings should be used for the next game .... and so on.

My issue is when the RATING in the PLAYERS sheet is updated it would recalculate all previous games as well, right?  How can I work around this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124187/discussion-on-question-by-grayson-robbins-calculations-based-on-a-dynamic-cell).